# how to perform the function asynchronously? (edited)

Tags: javascript, node.js

UPD:
How do I perform the encode function in my code asynchronously?
the problem is that encode with a lot of data takes a long time, i would like to encode asynchronously and then add everything to the response array and return to the user

code

```
var total = records.length
var data = []
var response = []
for(var i = 0; i < total; i++){
      data.push(records[i])
      response.push([
        records[i].userId,
        global.encode(data)
      ]);
  }
```

old question ( I was in a hurry and wrote the wrong question )
How to make the array appending asynchronously?
The problem is that during an iteration of the array i add new data to it and in the same iteration i need to encode it, with each iteration cycle it takes more and more time
question how can i encode and add to the array asynchronously in a synchronous function?
here is a code example (not working):

```
app.post('/encodeSomeData', cors(), (req, res) => {
  var i = 0
  var response = [];
  var records = req.body.data
  var data = []
  async function lol(){
      await encode(i)
      i++;
      if(i == records.length && response.length == records.length){
        res.send({
          success: true,
          result: response
        })
      }else{
        await lol();
      }
  }

  async function processMyArray (array, index) {
    array[1] = global.encode(array[1])
    response[index] = array
  }

  async function encode(j){
      console.log(j);
      data.push(records[j])
      await processMyArray([
        records[j].userId,
        data
      ], j)
  }
  lol();
});
```

Comment: I don't understand why `records[j].userId` is passed as an argument that is supposed to be `array`, and `data` is passed as argument that is supposed to be an index. Why do you want to assign the *same* array to *all* `response` entries (assuming you intended to assign `data`)? I don't really understand what you are trying to do here. Can you provide a time line of what you want to happen to the arrays?

Comment: Append data asynchronously? I'm not sure what you mean... Consider adding a minimum reproducible example

Comment: this code is probably bad (because I tried to rewrite it in async) in general I only need to encode in async, and after everything is ready insert in the array

Comment: "I don't understand why records[j].userId is passed as an argument" I need to get an array where the first element is userId and the second is the data after the encode

Comment: " I don't really understand what you are trying to do here" I have an array to encode, then I add to this array the next array to encode and so on ( this is a peculiarity, the logic is not broken, but it looks weird I agree )

same code in sync https://pastebin.com/ZhxAFSDw

Comment: It still isn't clear what you are trying to achieve or what the problematic code is. Why do you think making the code asynchronous is the solution? That adds complexity but doesn't affect how long the code takes to run, only when it runs. Your goal might be to unblock the main event loop so other requests can be handled, or it might be to speed up the encoding and there are potentially ways to do both of those which would make it asynchronous but only as a side effect. ([See the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).

Comment: It also isn't clear what `global.encode` actually does. Since it seems to be the part of the program that is causing you the problem, the specifics of how it works and what is does are relevant.

Comment: global.encode is a separate custom package, a very large data packaging

Comment: look at the code I posted above, during iteration I synchronously add data to the response array, one of which (the encode) is output in about 0.3 seconds
if i wait synchronously and send about 250 data in the form of records, then the response will take a very long time to assemble, so i want to somehow bring the encode and push function into asynchronous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can `map` array to `Array<Promise>` , and use `Promise.all`**

like this

```js
const addOneAsync = (i) =>
  new Promise((resolve) =>
    setTimeout(() => resolve(i + 1), Math.random() * 1000)
  );

const data = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const result = data.map(addOneAsync);

console.log(result.toString()); //Array<Promise>

Promise.all(result).then(console.log);
```

**In your case like this**

```js
const records = [{ userId: 1 }, { userId: 2 }, { userId: 3 }, { userId: 4 }, { userId: 5 }];

const encode = (arr) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(JSON.stringify(arr)), Math.random() * 1000));

const data = [];
const result = records.map(async (record) => {
  data.push(record);
  return [record.userId, await encode(data.concat())];
});

Promise.all(result).then(console.log);
```

Try this

```
const encode = (data) => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(global.encode(data)), 0));

app.post('/encodeSomeData', cors(), (req, res) => {
  const records = req.body.data;
  const data = [];
  const result = records.map(async (record) => {
    data.push(record);
    return [record.userId, await encode(data.concat())];
  });

  Promise.all(result).then((response) => res.send({ success: true, result: response }));
}
```

Comment: By the way, maybe you can watch this https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html

Comment: Thanks your solution helped me, but on top of that I also changed my express server by adding cluster and in combination with your solution it helped me:)

Answer (score 0):

I would use rxjs to set up an asychronous data pipe.

```
import {scheduled, asyncScheduler} from 'rxjs';
import {scan, map} from 'rxjs/operators';

function 
scheduled(
  records, // emit each record...
  asyncScheduler // ... asynchronously
).pipe(
  scan( // combine previously emitted and the current record, kind of like array.accumulate except it also emits each step
    (acc, r) => [
      r.userId,
      acc[1].push(r)
    ],
    [null, []] // this is the seed (the first acc)
  ), // at this point we have what we want except the second element isn't encoded, so...
  map(
    a => [a[0], global.encode(a[1])]
  )
).subscribe({ // without subscribe, we just have chained operations but haven't actually executed anything yet! Subcribe is what starts the flow.
  next: a => response.push(a)
})
```

Once debugged, this should asynchronously push values into response.

Why you would need or want to repeatedly encode `records[0]` a total of `records.length` times is beyond me but that wasn't part of your question.

Answer (score -1):

If your goal is to run multiple `Array.push()` instances simultaneously, this could work:

```js
async function push(data, array) {
  array.push(data)
}
```

Appending data is inherently synchronous, but a library like [Bacon](https://baconjs.github.io/) might be of use

Comment: my goal is to encode in async
and then fill the array with what is returned by async

p.s. i don't know js very well (i mean i don't write in it, the main languages are php/go)

Comment: That won't work. `array.push` is synchronous. Wrapping it in a Promise is just pointless complexity.

Comment: @Quentin `push(data, array)` runs in the background, so OP's code won't wait for `Array.push` to finish before moving on

Comment: @ivanovcol In that case, I highly recommend using a stream library like bacon instead of a standard `Array`